# Using template and controller multiple times on different routes in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my Ember application I have a categories controller and corresponding template.

I want to use this on various routes: When browsing, when advanced searching and when adding a product.

I tried to put it together as this:

```
#router
this.resource("categories", { path: "/*scope/select-category" }, function() {
} );
```

Scope could be `'search'`, `'products'` or `'products/new'`. It would make URLs very pretty!

But I'm having difficulties finding back the `*scope` value from my controller, I found it somewhere nested deeply, but with `'products/new'` as the scope the value is `'products'`.

Also I already experienced some strange behavior, for example, on a fresh page load for `'products/select-category'` it wants to go to `'products.product'`, trying to find the product with ID='select-category'. Which is of course  not what I want.

The categories route is the first route in the list so I assumed it would always pick that first..?

I'm doubting if this is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should do it this way, by handling the scope on a separate route:

```
#router
this.resource("scope", { path: "/scope/:scope" }, function() {
    this.route("categories", { path: "/select-category" }
} );
```

This way you can handle scope nicely in the ScopeRoute, with a proper scope parameter.

Comment: True, but this will mess up my pretty URLs, which is kind of a big deal for me. Will this also work when using a path like `"/:scope"` for the scope resource?

Comment: This indeed does the trick, I can get the scope from my controller with this: `"this.get('target').router.state.params.scope.name"`. One problem though, on fresh page load it tells me no route is matched. `Error: Assertion Failed: The URL '/products/new/select-category?parent=1' did not match any routes in your application`

Comment: I've opened up a new question for the fresh page load problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Turns out I just needed to use `"/*scope"` instead of `"/:scope"`. Would be great if you could update your answer correspondingly!

Comment: you can get the params much easier on the model hook of the scope route

Comment: The model hook is not always called on a route with dynamic segments right? Can't it give problems?

Comment: The model hook is not called only when you supply the actual model already in a link-to helper.
So that should not impose any problems in this case.